# HTACCESS ignores images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following very simple htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule a.jpg b.jpg
RewriteRule c.php d.php
```

All four resources are in the root folder.

The PHP rule works as expected, however, the JPG rule is just ignored as if it were not there. The image a.jpg continues to display.

I am completely clueless on why that would happen.

The only explanation I could think of is that Apache is somehow configured not to INVOKE htaccess at all if the requested resource is an image. Is that even possible?

Comment: Nope, tried on a different machine, same thing

Comment: "Apache is somehow configured not to INVOKE htaccess" - technically possible (to some degree), but extremely unlikely IMO. Do you have access to the server config? Check the network traffic in the browser - this will tell you exactly how this resource is being served.

Comment: Have you confirmed it's not a browser cache issue? Try incognito or clearing the cache somehow.

Comment: @jminardi The first comment (which has since been deleted for some reason), asked just that.

Comment: If not the browser cache, I would strongly suggest some kind of server-side caching or proxy cache. Switching machines would not necessarily clear this.

Comment: Please post the _exact_ URL you actually request.

Comment: If you have access to the server configuration, then find out what is actually happening, by enabling rewrite logging. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: thank you all for your comments. The solution is posted below

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason and I am posting my answer in case anyone faces the same issue.

It appears that both Nginx and Apache are configured on the server. Nginx is internet facing and Apache is internal.

It appears that the web hosting company has done so to benefit from Nginx's better performance and to provide compatibility to anyone coming from Apache environment at the same time.

When Nginx receives a PHP request from the internet it allows the request to pass through and reach Apache but when the resource is a static resource (image,  css, js) Nginx delivers the resource itself for optimum performance.

The htaccess image rule above is not processed because the request is not even reaching Apache.

I temporarily solved the problem by not allowing Nginx to handle the images itself and allowing them to proceed to Apache.

The better solution of course is to remove htaccess dependency and handle everything within Nginx configuration file, which I will be doing soon.

The best solution of course is to remove Apache completely but it is a shared server and I don't have full control.